# Running Selenium framework on CentOs

Tags: java, selenium, centos7, xvfb

I have tried using XVFB to run chrome headless on CentOs server, though I now have to update my code to do that, do we know if we can fire XVFB using Java code and make sure that the WebDriver is able to interact with it?

Edit: the example from the documentation

```
ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY", display))
    .build();
```

return new ChromeDriver(service);

Comment: Can you put an example of your code in your question?

Comment: Hi David, I haven't written any code yet. I am only playing around with the server. XVFB seemed to be the only thing that can get Chrome running, what I need to do is find some documentation on how to use it because the GitHub page didn't help. A reference from there is (check edit)

while saying that I need to start the virtual framebuffer before which doesn't help a lot.